# Add a text next to stock quantity if it is less than 10 in Woocommerce single product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, stock

I found this posted as a comment on another thread but I don't know what I'm supposed to do with it:

```
 if($product->get_stock_quantity() <10){echo 'Limited supply left';}
```

I figured it should have a hook. I tried **woocommerce_after_single_variation** but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `woocommerce_get_availability_text` filter hook with the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'filter_product_availability_text', 10, 2 );
function filter_product_availability_text( $availability_text, $product ) {

    if( $product->is_in_stock() && $product->managing_stock() && 
    ! $product-> is_on_backorder( 1 ) && $product->get_stock_quantity() < 10 ) {
        $availability_text .= ' ' . __("(limited supply left)", "woocommerce");
    }
    return $availability_text;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

[image]